# setTableEvent setter is no more available for Table with itext7

Tags: java, itext7

I am using itext7.
I have a table with a header and several normal rows. I have also put a page header from pageNumber > 1. So when the table is split on the next page I have the table header that overlaps the page header.

My goal is to put the split table header just below the page header so that there is no more overlap.

For that I want to put a table event and try to modify the table margin top when the split is happening.

With itext5, there was the setter setTableEvent that could be set for the PdfPTable with the use of PdfPTableEventForwarder to create the event.

How can I reach this goal with itext7 ?

My code is like this:

I have added the below handler for the END_PAGE event

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

pdf.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new MyHeaderEventHandler());
```

Snippet code of MyHeaderEventHandler class:

public void handleEvent(Event event){

//some code here

```
if(pageNumber > 1)
{

  Table pageHeaderTable = new Table(new float[]{1.5f, 1.3f, 1.5f, 2.3f, 2.3f, 2.3f, 2f, 2.6f});

 pageHeaderTable.setMarginTop(12).setWidth(523).setMarginLeft(36);

 pageHeaderTable.setFixedLayout();

//some code to fill pageHeaderTable cells(1 row with 8 cells) with string values

 canvas.add(pageHeaderTable);

}

 canvas.close();
 pdfCanvas.release();

}
```

//snippet of code for my invoiceElementTable

```
Table invoiceElementTable = new Table(new float[]{1.5f, 1.3f, 1.5f, 2.3f, 2.3f, 2.3f, 2f, 2.6f});
invoiceElementTable.setFixedLayout();
                                invoiceElementTable.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100));
invoiceElementTable.addHeaderCell(new Cell(1,8).add(new Paragraph("invoiceElementTable Header")));

I have a list of objects to fill the cells:

eltList.stream().forEach(elt-> {
invoiceElementTable.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(elt.getItem0)));
invoiceElementTable.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(elt.getItem1)));
invoiceElementTable.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(elt.getItem2)));
invoiceElementTable.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(elt.getItem3)));
invoiceElementTable.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(elt.getItem4)));
invoiceElementTable.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(elt.getItem5)));
invoiceElementTable.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(elt.getItem6)));
invoiceElementTable.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(elt.getItem7)));
});
```

The problem is when invoiceElementTable is split to the next page, its header row ("invoiceElementTable Header") overlaps the unique row of the pageHeaderTable.

I want to modify the position of invoiceElementTable when it is split to the next page in order to avoid the overlap

Comment: Hi, please show us what you have tried and the code that reproduces the problem as well as the desired result. Right now the description is quite vague.

Comment: I have updated my post with some snippet of my code.I hope it is clear now

Comment: *"I have the table header that overlaps the page header."* - this usually is due to a mispositioned page header. IMO you should try and fix this by properly positioning the page header instead of by manipulating page content bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement your own table renderer and specify the layout area for the split parts of the table.

In the sample below the layout rectangle has been decreased by 100 (you need to change this value with the height of your page header):

```
    class CustomTableRenderer extends TableRenderer {
    public CustomTableRenderer(Table modelElement) {
        super(modelElement);
    }

    @Override
    public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
        return new CustomTableRenderer((Table)modelElement);
    }

    @Override
    public LayoutResult layout(LayoutContext layoutContext) {
        if (!isOriginalNonSplitRenderer) {
            LayoutArea area = layoutContext.getArea();
            area.setBBox(area.getBBox().decreaseHeight(100));
        }
        return super.layout(layoutContext);
    }
}
```

To integrate it into your code, just set the instance of this renderer on your table:

```
table.setNextRenderer(new CustomTableRenderer(table));
```